# Constraints for labels with changing size

Tags: swift, constraints

Pic. 1

[image]

Pic. 2

[image]

Pic.1 - it is a structure of my `ViewController`. `Label1` and `Label2` have changing size (content comes from backend) for different users. If content of labels is small, I need to set Top Space constraint for `TableView` (vertical spacing) to Button (pic.1), but if content of labels is big,  set Top Space constraint for `TableView` (vertical spacing) to Stack (pic.2). How to set constraints for `TableView`?

Comment: So if I understand You correctly, You would like to set programically Top Constraint for TableView ?

Comment: @Sebastianor I use Storyboard, better to set constraints in Storyboard

Comment: So what do you mean to create constrains for TableView? You can create two constrains as You said and set one of them on isActive = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed your image,button two labels and stack in a view.
Then add following constraints

1. Top, leading and trailing to new container view
2. vertical space b/w container and table.
3. Required constraints for your image,button two labels and stack
4. Don't add bottom constraint for button.
5. Add bottom spacing to stack to its superview(embedded container) with a >=.
6. Height to container view with minimum height and set priority to low(250)

[image] [image]

Comment: used your solution right now, it works greate. Thanx

Comment: (y) happy coding